who can explain `foo, bar = foo[bar] = [1,2,3], 2`? (python)
I cannot understand the code as follows:
>>> foo, bar = foo[bar] = [1,2,3], 2
>>> foo
>>> [1, 2, ([...], 2)]
>>> bar
>>> 2

In my opinion,
>>> foo, bar = foo[bar] = [1,2,3], 2

is a multiply assignments, which can be written as:
>>> foo[bar] = [1,2,3], 2
>>> foo, bar = foo[bar]

obviously, the 1st assignment will cause error.
However, the foo, bar = foo[bar] = [1,2,3], 2 is amazingly legal, and show me a strange result.
who can explain why?
I expecting that someone can explain to me.

The assignments are done left to right, so it's foo, bar = [1, 2, 3], 2 first: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-assignment_stmt

Just to clarify, when there are multiple assignments in one statement, we need to skip past the last = to find the expression that defines the value.  Then, do the assignments in left-to-right order, to each target we skipped past when searching for the last =.
